# How does a computer 'know' what memory is allocated?

Tags: c++, memory

When memory is allocated in a computer, how does it know which bytes are already occupied and can't be overwritten?

So if these are some bytes of memory that aren't being used:

```
[0|0|0|0]
```

How does the computer know whether they are or not? They could just be an integer that equals zero. Or it could be empty memory. How does it know?

Comment: The computer doesn't know.  It will write anywhere you tell it (assuming that the hardware memory protect circuitry allows it).

Answer (score 10):

That depends on the way the allocation is performed, but it generally involves manipulation of data belonging to the allocation mechanism.

When you allocate some variable in a function, the allocation is performed by decrementing the stack pointer. Via the stack pointer, your program knows that anything below the stack pointer is not allocated to the stack, while anything above the stack pointer is allocated.

When you allocate something via `malloc()` etc. on the heap, things are similar, but more complicated: all theses allocators have some internal data structures which they never expose to the calling application, but which allow them to select which memory addresses to return on an allocation request. Some `malloc()` implementation, for instance, use a number of memory pools for small objects of fixed size, and maintain linked lists of free objects for each fixed size which they track. That way, they can quickly pop one memory region of that list, only doing more expensive computations when they run out of regions to satisfy a certain request size.

---

In any case, each of the allocators have to request memory from the system kernel from time to time. This mechanism always works on complete memory pages (usually 4 kiB), and works via the syscalls `brk()` and `mmap()`. Again, the kernel keeps track of which pages are visible in which processes, and at which addresses they are mapped, so there is additional memory allocated inside the kernel for this.

These mappings are made available to the processor via the page tables, which uses them to resolve the virtual memory addresses to the physical addresses. So here, finally, you have some hardware involved in the process, but that is really far, far down in the guts of the mechanics, much below anything that a userspace process is ever able to see. Still, even the page tables are managed by the software of the kernel, not by the hardware, the hardware only interpretes what the software writes into the page tables.

Comment: Here your speaking about what's happening from the point of view of some running program, which heavily relies on the OS.

Comment: @hivert Didn't see your comment while I was already writing about the part that the kernel plays in the whole game :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I have the impression that you believe that there is some unoccupied memory that doesn't holds any value. That's wrong. You can imagine the memory as a very large array when each box contains a value whereas someone put something in it or not. If a memory was never written, then it contains a random value.

Now to answer your question, it's not the computer (meaning the hardware) but the operating system. It holds somewhere in its memory some tables recording which part of the memory are used. Also any byte of memory can be overwriten.

Comment: So it uses memory to know what memory is occupied? That seems not so efficient, but thanks!

Comment: The computer has one the memory to remember something (here which part of the memory is used or not). From the point of view of the OS, there us a unit called the Memory Management Unit, which has some memory specifically dedicated for that.

Comment: I did know about the large array thing though I just didn't know how the computer would know not to overwrite used memory.

Comment: If you bring virtual memory into the discussion, there is unoccupied memory that doesn't hold any value.

Comment: @user3452725 inefficient compared to what? There aren't many places a computer can remember things. There is the CPU itself (very limited space), memory, disk, and the network.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot tell by looking at content of memory at some location whether that portion of memory is used or not.  Memory value '0' does not mean the memory is not used.

To tell what portions of memory are used you need some structure to tell you this.  For example, you can divide memory into chunks and keep track of which chunks are used and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

There are memory blocks, they have an occupied or not occupied. On the heap, there are very complex data structures which organise it. But the answer to your question is too broad.